# For $y \in X_K := X \otimes _k K$ ($K$ : algebraically closed) lying over $x\in X$(closed point), the residue field $\kappa(y)=K$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, proof of Theorem 6.28 (p.159) and some question arises.

Let $k$ be a field, $X$ a $k$-scheme locally of finite type, and let $x \in X$ be a closed point.
And let $K$ be an algebraically closed extension of $k$. And write $X_K = X \otimes_k K$.

Let $y$ be a point of $X_K$ which is lying over $x$.

Then the residue field $\kappa(y)$ is $K$?

My first strategy is using that : https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C4Y

There, the Lemma 33.5.1. states that

> Lemma 33.5.1. Let $K/k$ be an extension of fields. Let $X$ be scheme over $k$ and set $Y=X_K$. If $y∈Y$ with image $x∈X$, then

> (1) $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} → \mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ is a faithfully flat local ring homomorphism,
>
> (2) with $\mathfrak{p}_0:=\operatorname{Ker}(κ(x)⊗_kK→κ(y))$ we have $κ(y)=κ(\mathfrak{p}_0)$,
>
> (3)$\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}=(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}⊗_k K)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ where $\mathfrak{p}⊂\mathcal{O}_{X,x}⊗_k K$ is the inverse image of $\mathfrak{p}_0$.
>
> (4)we have $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}/\mathfrak{m}_x\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}=(κ(x)⊗_kK)_{\mathfrak{p}_0}$

We will use the Lemma 33.5.1.-(2).

Here, $\psi : \kappa(x) \otimes_{k} K \to \kappa(y)$ maybe $(a \otimes b) \mapsto \varphi_1(a) \varphi_2(b)$ , where $\varphi_1 : \kappa(x) \to \kappa(y)$, $\varphi_2 : K \to \kappa(y)$ are induced field homomorphisms from $\pi_{1,y}^{\sharp} : \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \to \mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ and $\pi_{2,y}^{\sharp} : \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}K, \pi_{2}(y)} \to \mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$.
( $\pi_1 : Y=X_K \to X, \pi_2 : Y=X_K \to \operatorname{Spec}(K)$)

Now, from the Lemma 33.5.1., we want to show that $\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_0)= K$. Let $A:=\kappa(x) \otimes _k K$. Then to show $\kappa(\mathfrak{p}_0)= K$, is suffices to show that $Q(A/\mathfrak{p}_0) \cong K$, where $Q(A/\mathfrak{p}_0)$ is the quotient field.

Since $x\in X$ is a closed point(assumption), the residue field $\kappa(x)$ is a finite extension of $k$ (his book prop.3.33). In particular, there exists a $k$-embedding $i: \kappa(x) \hookrightarrow K$

Now, I'm trying to construct an isomorphism $\eta : Q(A/\mathfrak{p}_0) \to K$ as

$$\frac{(f_1 \otimes f_2) + \mathfrak{p}_0}{(g_1 \otimes g_2)+\mathfrak{p}_0} \mapsto \
   \frac{i(f_1)f_2}{i(g_1)g_2} $$

And I'm stuck at showing that $\eta$ is well-defined homomorphism.
It seems possible to show the injectivity and surjectivity (true?)

Should we try to use that $X$ is locally of finite type over $k$ and $K$ is an algebraically closed? Then, how?

And.. there is also a possibility for the proof that first we construct a ring homomorphism $K \to Q(A/\mathfrak{p}_0)$ and second, showing that the field extension $K \to Q(A/\mathfrak{p}_0)$ is algebraic, and use the algebraically closedness of $K$.

**Further progress** : My question is, can we choose such a $k$-embedding (above)
$i: \kappa(x) \to K$ such that $\varphi_1 = \varphi_2 \circ i$? If so, it seems possible to construct an isomorphism $K \to Q(A/\mathfrak{p}_0)$ ; i.e., let's define

$$ \eta : K \to Q(A/\mathfrak{p}_0)$$

$$ \frac{f}{g} \mapsto \frac{(1 \otimes f) + \mathfrak{p}_0}{(1  \otimes g) + \mathfrak{p}_0}$$

Note that if our question ($\varphi_1 = \varphi_2 \circ i$) is true, then for $f_1 \in \kappa(x)$ and $f_2 \in K$,
$ (1\otimes i(f_1)f_2) + \mathfrak{p}_0 = (f_1 \otimes f_2) + \mathfrak{p}_0 $, by the definition of $\mathfrak{p}_0 = \operatorname{ker} \psi$.

Then, we maybe show that the $\eta$ is surjective since for

$u := \frac{(f_{1,1} \otimes f_{1,2} + \cdots + f_{n,1}\otimes f_{n,2}) + \mathfrak{p}_0}{(g_{1,1} \otimes g_{1,2} + \cdots + g_{m,1} \otimes g_{m,2} ) + \mathfrak{p}_0} \in Q(A/\mathfrak{p}_0) $ ($A:=\kappa(x) \otimes _k K$),

$$\eta( \frac{i(f_{1,1})f_{1,2} + \cdots + i(f_{n,1})f_{n,2} }{ i(g_{1,1})g_{1,2} + \cdots + i(g_{m,1})g_{m,2} } ) = u$$

(True?)

So, the question $\varphi_1 = \varphi_2 \circ i$ is true?

Or..is there any other simpler method?

Anyway, can anyone help?

This question originates from next proof of the theorem 6.28 in Gortz's book :

[image]

[image]

Q. Why the underlined statement is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y \in X_K$ lying above $x$. In particular, $\underline{y}:\mathrm{Spec}\,\kappa(y) \rightarrow X_K$ is the composition of $i: \mathrm{Spec}\,\kappa(y) \to \mathrm{Spec}\,\kappa(x) \times_k \mathrm{Spec}\,K$ and $\underline{x}_K: \mathrm{Spec}\,\kappa(x) \times_k K \rightarrow X_K$.

Since $x$ is a closed point, the natural morphism $\underline{x}: \mathrm{Spec}\,\kappa(x) \rightarrow X$ is a closed immersion, thus $\underline{x}_K$ is a closed immersion.

Since $x$ is a closed point, $\kappa(x)$ is a finite $k$-algebra, hence $\kappa(x) \otimes_k K$ is a finite $K$-algebra and its spectrum is finite discrete. Thus the set-theoretic image of $\underline{x}_K$ is a finite discrete set of closed points, and in particular $y$ is a closed point.

Therefore $\kappa(y)$ is a finite extension of $K$. Since $K$ is algebraically closed, $\kappa(y)=K$.

Comment: O.K. I understand your overall strategy. Can I ask a question? 1) Why $\operatorname{Spec}\kappa(y) \to X_K$ and $ j : \operatorname{Spec} \kappa(x) \times_k \operatorname{Spec}K  \to X_K$ are closed immersion? 2) Why $\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(y) \to X_K$ factors through $i : \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(y) \to \operatorname{Spec} \kappa(x) \times_k \operatorname{Spec}K $? Where can I find an assoicated reference? Anyway, Thank you~

Comment: 1) $j$ is a base change of $\{x\} \rightarrow X$ which is a closed immersion since $x$ is a closed point. The other map is not, I made a mistake (probably edited by the time you read it). 2) it’s basically the property of fibers of a morphism (here, the fiber at $x$ of the morphism $X_K \rightarrow X$).

Comment: Let me follow your comment. First, let $l : \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(y) \to X_K$ be the canonical map. Then proof of the composition $ l= j \circ i$ (factorization) involves some commutative diagram-argument(true?) ( in particular, maybe involving $\operatorname{Spec}(\varphi_1)$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(\varphi_2)$ in the above our question). Second, let $(0) \in \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(y)$. Then we have $l^{\sharp}_{(0)} = i^{\sharp}_{(0)} \circ j^{\sharp}_{i(0)}$ So if $l^{\sharp}_{(0)}$ is surjective(true?), then  $i^{\sharp}_{(0)}$ is also surjective and so $i$ is a closed immersion.

Comment: And $l^{\sharp}_{(0)}$ is really surjective?

Comment: And..it seems that the condition "$j$ is closed immersion" is redundant. Let $ p_1 : \operatorname{Spec}(\kappa(x) \otimes_k K ) \to \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(x)$ , $ \pi_1 : X_K \to X$ be the natural projections, and let $\psi : \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(x) \to X$ be the canonical morphism. If $\pi_1 \circ j = \psi \circ p_1$ is cartesian diagram, then since $\psi$ is closed immersion, $j$ is also closed immersion. But how can we gaurantee that the diagram  $\pi_1 \circ j = \psi \circ p_1$ is cartesian? Am I pointing out correctly? 'closed immersionness of j' is needed?

Comment: Uhm..to gaurantee that "$i$ is closed immersion" in my comment, it seems that it also needs to show that $i$ is topological closed immersion. And how..

Comment: To prove that $l=j \circ i$, you can check it on every coordinate. Depending on how deep into the basics you want to dive, there may be some commutative diagrams to deal with. $l^{\sharp}_{(0)}$ is obviously surjective if you write everything explicitly in an affine open. I agree that the condition on $j$ is redundant. Once we have $i^{\sharp}_{(0)}$ surjective, we can just say that $\mathrm{Spec}\,\kappa(x) \times_k \mathrm{Spec}\,K$ is finite over $K$ so a finite disjoint union of closed points, so (by definition!) $i$ closed immersion, which concludes.

Comment: Yes. If $\operatorname{Spec}\kappa(x) \times_k \operatorname{Spec}K$ if finite over $K$, then $\kappa(x) \otimes_k K$ is artinian and has dimension zero and game is over(?) And, how can we deduce that(finiteness over $K$) from the surjectivity of $i^{\sharp}_{(0)}$ (I'll try to show that). Can you explain more in detail?~

Comment: Uhm.. or we can show the artinianess of $\kappa(x) \otimes_k K$ directly by noting $\kappa(x)$ is finite extension of $k$, as you answered ; i.e., we maybe don't need to use the surjectivity of $i^{\sharp}_{(0)}$ to show finiteness of $\kappa(x) \otimes_k K$ over $K$.

Comment: It seems that puzzle(?) is (almost) completed :)

Comment: Exactly: we don’t need anything about $i$ to say that $\kappa(x) \otimes K$ is finite over $K$, it’s just because $\kappa(x)$ is finite over $k$.

Comment: Yes. I'm now struggling to show that the $l^{\sharp}_{(0)}$ is surjective through some calculaton and it seems that I reach almost to the proof, althogh there are some few suspicious things. Anyway, thanks for valuable and helpful comment !

Comment: O.K. It is more succint answer. I got it. Thank you. Btw, perhaps, (for you), is there more simpler way to prove the factorization $\underline{y} = \underline{x}_K \circ i$ ?

Comment: It’s just the fact that a map to $X_K$ is determined by its $X$ component and its $\mathrm{Spec}\,K$ component and that they are the same on both sides?

Comment: What $X$ component, $\operatorname{Spec}K$ component exactly means? I have a little feeling about your intention but I don't know how can I figure out it. Anyway, I think it can be proven rigorously by brutal force using universal property but I don't know how can you 'intuitively' reach to concluion that they are same on both side. Perhaps, can you explain it more in detail? I want to learn some kind of secret(?) that would allow me to easily guess some kind factorization under special situations.